# How to force QueryToJson to quote all values?

Tags: json, coldfusion

I have the code for QueryToJSON

```
<cffunction name="queryToJSON" returntype="string" access="public" output="yes">
  <cfargument name="q" type="query" required="yes" />
  <cfset var o=ArrayNew(1)>
  <cfset var i=0>
  <cfset var r=0>
  <cfloop query="Arguments.q">
    <cfset r=Currentrow>
    <cfloop index="i" list="#LCase(Arguments.q.columnList)#">
      <cfset o[r][i]=Evaluate(i)>
    </cfloop>
  </cfloop>
  <cfreturn SerializeJSON(o)>
</cffunction>
```

It works very well. The only issue is the `key: value` pairs.  The `value` is not always surrounded by double quotes. I want all the values to be surrounded by double quotes.

What can I change to make that happen?

Example: Desired result:

```
{"zoho_item_name": "Shipping Charges",
      "id": "128177000000051618",
      "tms_name": "***Ship My book to me before class***",
      "sku": "",
      "description": "Shipping",
      "rate": "6.57",
      "Account": "Shipping Fees",
      "taxable": "true",
      "ExemptionReason": "",
      "Source": "2",
      "ReferenceId": "",
      "LastSyncTime": "",
      "Status": "Active",
      "Usageunit": "",
      "PurchaseRate": "0.00",
      "PurchaseAccount": "",
      "PurchaseDescription": "",
      "InventoryAccount": "",
      "ReorderPoint": "",
      "Vendor": "",
      "InitialStock": "",
      "InitialStockRate": "",
      "ItemType": "Sales"
    }
```

Actual result:

```
{
    "initialstockrate": "",
    "inventoryaccount": "",
    "usageunit": "",
    "rate": 7.65,
    "tms_name": "***Ship my item(s) to me before class***",
    "taxable": true,
    "description": "Shipping",
    "sku": "",
    "purchaseaccount": "",
    "purchaserate": 0.00,
    "status": "Active",
    "account": "Shipping Fees",
    "lastsynctime": "",
    "initialstock": "",
    "zoho_item_name": "Shipping Charges",
    "source": 2,
    "exemptionreason": "",
    "id": 128177000000051618,
    "reorderpoint": "",
    "referenceid": "",
    "vendor": "",
    "itemtype": "Sales",
    "purchasedescription": ""
}
```

Comment: Your only argument is a query object.  It can have numeric, string, and date datatypes.  It can also have null values.  If you want double quotes, it's the job of your function to put them there, not the job of the incoming query object.

Comment: which function, when i call query, i pass the query to querytojson and it gives me this back, also all my fields are varchar, so even i try doing cast or convert does not help here

Answer (score 0):

Typically speaking, boolean values and numbers should not be strings. That removes the entire point of true/false and numbers in the first place. However, you can solve this by using [`ToString`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f9e.html).

```
<cfset o[r][i]= ToString(Evaluate(i))>
```

Comment: `toString` does seems to be solving it

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: sorry i mean to say, it did not worked, damm me, how i can be so stupid in missing that word